# Kendo UI Treeview's JSON is not updated. Loading in progress

Tags: jquery, json, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am using kendo UI tree view. In click event i call the method(for createJson data), which is updated the json data and feed into tree view data.

whenever i create json data. If it is Even times(2, 4,8..), Treeview showing correctly. But if it odd, Tree view is not loading Still shows Loading Message

```
net=[]
$(function(){
treeForm(net);
    $(document).on("click", "#siteCreation", function(event){
        addSite(net);   
    });
});
```

In function of update the json

```
function addSite(net){
// Update the json
treeForm(net)
}
```

Creation of tree is

```
function treeForm(net){
        var viewModel = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
            data:net,
           });

        var treeview = $("#tree").kendoTreeView({
            dataSource: viewModel,
            dataTextField: ["UID"],
            loadOnDemand: false
        }).data("kendoTreeView");
    }
```

Here Even time Updation of json is working but not in odd Time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are initializing multiple times a `kendoTreeView` on the same DOM element and that is not correct.

Since the only thing that you need is updating the data, what you should do is query if there is a `kendoTreeView` already in the element `tree` and if so update the data.

Something like:

```
  function treeForm(net){
    // Get the Kendo TreeView object
    var treeview = $("#tree").data("kendoTreeView");
    // Check if exists
    if (treeview) {
      // If exists update the data
      treeview.dataSource.data(net);
    } else {
      // if does not exist then create the HierarchicalDataSource and the TreeView
      var viewModel = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        data:net,
      });

      treeview = $("#tree").kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: viewModel,
        dataTextField: ["UID"],
        loadOnDemand: false
      }).data("kendoTreeView");
    }
```

A runnable snippet showing the solution

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  net=[
    { UID : "node1" },
    { UID : "node2" },
    { UID : "node3" }
  ];
  treeForm(net);
  $(document).on("click", "#siteCreation", function(event){
    addSite(net);   
  });

  function addSite(net){
    // Update the json
    net=[
      { UID : "node1" },
      { UID : "node2" },
      { UID : "node3" },
      { UID : "node4" }
    ];
    treeForm(net)
  }

  function treeForm(net){
    var treeview = $("#tree").data("kendoTreeView");

    if (treeview) {
      treeview.dataSource.data(net);
    } else {
      var viewModel = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        data:net,
      });

      treeview = $("#tree").kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: viewModel,
        dataTextField: ["UID"],
        loadOnDemand: false
      }).data("kendoTreeView");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<button id="siteCreation" class="k-button">Create</button>
<div id="tree"></div>
```